# Azure self-hosted integration runtime on a standalone machine

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have an on-premises MS-SQL Server where all the data is stored, which is also a backend for an application. From this on-premises server, we would like to copy data to Azure Data Lake using Data Factory service. This would require installation of Azure self-hosted integration runtime on application backend server.

Is there any other way, like, to create a standalone server for IR installation and use this IR for data copy activity from application backend to Data Lake?

Comment: It is a good practice to mention a cause of why this question deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see a problem with that, you dont have to install it on the same server. Point number 3 talks about this:

> The self-hosted integration runtime doesn't need to be on the same
>   machine as the data source. However, having the self-hosted
>   integration runtime close to the data source reduces the time for the
>   self-hosted integration runtime to connect to the data source. We
>   recommend that you install the self-hosted integration runtime on a
>   machine that differs from the one that hosts the on-premises data
>   source. When the self-hosted integration runtime and data source are
>   on different machines, the self-hosted integration runtime doesn't
>   compete with the data source for resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir

Comment: I was almost there. Wasn't aware we can configure it as well, providing screenshot below for others ref. and I hope this solves the problem. This way we can access production data as well .. need to check if we can connect to multiple servers using this configuration .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install IR on the on-premise machine and then configure it using Launch Configuration Manager. Doesn't need to be on the same machine as the data source. Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-powershell#create-linked-services).

[image]